# How to override a property after importing few property files in application yml in springboot 2.4

Tags: spring-boot

I have two property files in yml

1. application-common.yml with below content

   ```yaml
   web-client:
     max-connections: 500
   wait-for:
     time: 1s
   ```
2. application.yml with below content

   ```yaml
   info:
     app:
       name: "@project.name@"
       version: "@project.version@"
   spring:
     application.name: "@project.name@"

   ---
   spring:
     config:
       activate.on-profile: local
       import: classpath:application-common.yml
   wait-for:
     time: 10s

   ---
   spring:
     config:
       activate.on-profile: prod
       import: classpath:application-common.yml
   wait-for:
     time: 5s
   ```

I was expecting that I should be able to override `wait-for` property after importing `application-common.yml` to `10s` for the `local` profile and `5s` for the `prod` profile. But when I run the application with `local` profile, the `wait-for` property is resolved to `1s` instead of `10s`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very sure about this response since I haven't testet it, but I think the standard layout should rather be as follows:

- `application.yml` <= shared/common stuff
- `application-local.yml` <= `local` profile specific overrides
- `application-prod.yml` <= `prod` profile specific overrides

At least, that's how I would intuitively do it to follow best practices and would expect it to work.

Comment: that would have worked if I had a single place where all common properties are defined. But let say, I have profile called `prod-east` that needs to import properties from `application.yml` and `application-prod.yml` and override a property.

Comment: I don't think there is a concept of "hierarchical profiles". Sounds a bit like overkill to me. Isn't a file `application-prod-east.yml` that extends `application.yml` enough for the profile? This somehow sounds safer/clearer to me than some fancy multi-level profile inheritance. If you have so many profiles, perhaps you should look at something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the property by redefining it in another yml or properties file. But make sure that, which ever property file gets read at last, those properties will be effective/considered in the application.

e.g. if your common yml file gets read last, then "wait-for" will be 1s & if application yml file gets read last, then "wait-for" will be 10s.

Comment: yeap that should work. I was trying to avoid creating a new file just for override properties. I was hoping if I can do inline. But looks like there is no other way.

Comment: One more thing you can do is, if you do not define "wait-for" property in any props file, then you can give default value while using/injecting it in application (but this is on code level change, which is not recommended always).